# vb.net what is a good way of displaying a decimal with a given maximum length

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, decimal, formatting

I am writing a custom totaling method for a grid view. I am totaling fairly large numbers so I'd like to use a decimal to get the total. The problem is I need to control the maximum length of the total number. To solve this problem I started using float but it doesn't seem to support large enough numbers, I get this in the totals column(1.551538E+07). So is there some formating string I can use in .ToString() to guarentee that I never get more then X characters in the total field? Keep in mind I'm totaling integers and decimals.

Comment: What I'm saying is I have a cell that has a maximum usable width. If you have a decimal and you just use decimal.ToString() you could get a number like "0.333333333" for 1/3, if I limit the number of characters to say 5 I should get "0.333". I will make sure that I have enough room to represent any whole number, so not worried about your concern. I can't just say get the decimal with a certain prescision because I could have either of the following numbers to total "1325316.0" OR "2.32561561". so if I limit it to 7 characters I'd get "1325316" OR "2.32561".

Comment: NOTE, it would be ideal if there was a formater that would do this for me, as apposed to complex string logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with all numbers displaying in scientific notation, you could go with `"E[numberOfDecimalPlaces]"` as your format string.

For example, if you want to cap your strings at, say, 12 characters, then, accounting for the one character for the decimal point and five characters needed to display the exponential part, you could do:

```
Function FormatDecimal(ByVal value As Decimal) As String
    If value >= 0D Then
        Return value.ToString("E5")
    Else
        ' negative sign eats up another character '
        Return value.ToString("E4")
    End If
End Function
```

Here's a simple demo of this function:

```
Dim d(5) As Decimal

d(0) = 1.203D
d(1) = 0D
d(2) = 1231234789.432412341239873D
d(3) = 33.3218403820498320498320498234D
d(4) = -0.314453908342094D
d(5) = 000032131231285432940D

For Each value As Decimal in d
    Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(value))
Next
```

Output:

```
1.20300E+000
0.00000E+000
1.23123E+009
3.33218E+001
-3.1445E-001
3.21312E+016
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Decimal.Round, but I don't understand the exact question, it sounds like you're saying that if the total adds up to 12345.67, you might only want to show 4 digits and would then show 2345 or do you just mean that you want to remove the decimals?